# Why does string[-1:0] return '' in Python?

Tags: python

```
>>> sample = "asdf"
>>> sample[-1:0]
```

I thought it would start with the last character up to the first position (but not including). However, it returns `''` when I expected `f`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Search "understanding python's splice notation"

Comment: good suggestion

Comment: Well a `str` is nothing more than a series of states. So why not `sample[-1]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go backwards *towards* the first element, you need a third argument to your slice, the *stride*:

```
sample[-1:0:-1]
```

This defaults to `1`, which moves forward one step at a time; setting it to `-1` moves backwards instead.

Comment: what if the last step is 0? I guess it doesn't move? and if it's 2 then it moves to the left two at a time?

Comment: @jojojo when they say "last piece" they mean the "c" in sample[a:b:c]

Comment: Python 1.4 introduced the third ("step" / "stride") element of slice notation.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The user expected the value "f", your response delivers the value "fds".

Comment: @schoulten, the OP accepted it; that's direct evidence as to their expectations. (They didn't say they _wanted_ `f`, they said they _expected_ `f`; it was a "why does X happen?" question, not a "how do I do Y?" question)

Answer (score 0):

Remember the way to go about it is start, stop and step in the square brackets, you got the order wrong!